# jQuery, Html5 audio player submit form after finished

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to detect html5 audio player when finished?

I'd like to submit a form after the audio is finished.

```
    <audio controls>
      <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">      
      Your browser does not support the audio tag.
    </audio> 

    $( document ).ready(function() {
    // when audio finished
        $(".form_sub #submit").trigger('click');
    });
<form class="form_sub">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waGVMR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of events associated with the audio player. This may be what you are looking for.

```
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
aud.onended = function() {
    alert("The audio has ended");
};
```

More can be found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp

Answer (score 1):

The `<audio>` element has an `ended` event that you can listen for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

You might need to do some testing to weed out some quirks and to determine browser support.